# Sum months from January to latest available month for current year, and previous year

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am trying to find a way to do a year to date for the current and previous year.
For example, for the **current year I would sum from January to latest available**, and then the same months from the previous year, January to July in this case.
If the latest available month is July of 2020, then I want January to July of 2019 summed and January to July of 2020 summed.

I have cut the script back to the barebones and added the dput():

```
library(tidyverse)
  
  #Get the data for table 1
  data1 <- read_csv("test-table.csv")
  data1
  
  dput(data1)
  
  data1 <- data1 %>%
    select(DATE, TC, VALUE) 

  dput(data1)
 structure(list(DATE = structure(c(18444, 18444, 18444), class = "Date"), 
  TC = c("Canada", "Canada", "Canada"), VALUE = c(141772, 113414, 
  100351)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
  REF_DATE = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
  "collector")), GEO = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
  "collector")), DGUID = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
  "collector")), `Traveller characteristics` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
  "collector")), UOM = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
  "collector")), UOM_ID = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
  "collector")), SCALAR_FACTOR = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
  "collector")), SCALAR_ID = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
  "collector")), VECTOR = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
  "collector")), COORDINATE = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
  "collector")), VALUE = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
  "collector")), STATUS = structure(list(), class = c("collector_logical", 
  "collector")), SYMBOL = structure(list(), class = c("collector_logical", 
  "collector")), TERMINATED = structure(list(), class = c("collector_logical", 
  "collector")), DECIMALS = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
  "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: do you care about the TC column?

Comment: Yes, I still need the TC column, unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the data is tidy, it's a simple `filter` to remove months you're not interested in, `group`ing by `year` and `tc`, and `summarize` to get the `sum`med total of the `value`s for each `tc`.

To get a dynamic month list, use the `unique` month values from the `months_df` which is `filter`ed to only contain the latest year (`max`).  We can then use that as our `filter` for our final `summary` df.

```
library(tidyverse)

# tidy up the data
tidy_data <- data1 %>%
  separate(`DATE    TC  VALUE`, into = c("date", 'tc', 'value'), sep = '\t') %>%
  separate(date, into = c('year', 'month'), sep = '-') %>%
  mutate_at(.vars = c('year','month','value'), .funs = as.integer) 

# filter for latest year
months_df <- tidy_data %>%
  filter(year == max(tidy_data$year))

# use months_df to feed the filter
summary <- tidy_data %>%
  filter(month %in% unique(months_df$month)) %>%
  group_by(year, tc) %>%
  summarize(total = sum(value, na.rm = TRUE))
```

```
   year tc       total
  <int> <chr>    <int>
1  2019 TC-1  18271577
2  2019 TC-2  14094089
3  2019 TC-3   9415440
4  2020 TC-1   4340588
5  2020 TC-2   3431912
6  2020 TC-3   2551697
```

Edit: Updated to have a dynamic month list based on the latest year.  I'm sure there is a more elegant way, but this should work.

Comment: This is pretty close to what I'm looking for, but as this updates each month I would want it to update. For example, I would need the filter(month %in% c(1:7)) to update to filter(month %in% c(1:8)) and so on for each month

Comment: First off, thank you very much for your efforts. I think I am having an issue because the dput() I gave is not quite the same as the one in my app.r file. In app.r I am using a URL to get the CSV and in the example I trimmed it down too much.

Answer (score 0):

```
d <- IS YOUR DATA

d %>%
  group_by(date, tc) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(value = sum(value)) %>%
  mutate(month = month(date, label = T),
         year = year(date)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(month, year, tc, value) %>%
  split(.$tc) %>%
  map( ~ spread(.x, year, value, fill = 0) %>%
         mutate(across(where(is.numeric), cumsum))) %>%
  plyr::ldply(rbind) %>%
  select(month, tc, `2018`, `2019`, `2020`) %>%
  filter(month == month(Sys.Date(), label = T))

   month   tc    2018     2019    2020
1  Oct   TC-1      NA 28451012 4340588
2  Oct   TC-2 7518039 21795738 3431912
3  Oct   TC-3 4930193 14477761 2551697
```